# How do I modify, disable, or delete a task with stored credentials after a Server Name Change?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, task-scheduler

I have a task that's been running regularly every 30 minutes for several months. It's got stored credentials for my account, listed as `MACHINE_NAME\USER`. After the creation of this task, we decided to rename this server, so now my credentials are `NEW_MACHINE_NAME\USER`. In both cases I've selected "Run whether the user is logged on or not and stored my password."

I've got a new task that I want to replace the old one, and although I'm able to set it up and got it working, now I can't disable or delete the old one.

When I try to access it, it says

> An error has occurred for task [task-name]. Error message: The specified account name is not valid.

followed by

> The task could not be modified as requested.

Is it possible to Run As a user named with the former server name? Any other way to override my former self?

Comment: As a workaround, I was able to edit the target PowerShell script for the original scheduled task to be a no-op, since I still had access to that.

Comment: Are you using a Windows Server 2008 server?  If so, there is a hotfix available for this situation.  Seems as though the problem is related to the task having a different servername(NETBIOS). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/953153

Comment: I'm on Win 2012 R2. Also, I just connected over RDP using `OLD-MACHINE-NAME\user`, but it just resumed my session. When I then ran `whoami`, it gave me `NEW-MACHINE-NAME\user`.

Comment: Check for the task in registry here `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks` make a backup of the key and remove it

Comment: @Drifter104 Thanks, but I'm a bit leery of trying that maneuver on my production server. I'm content having the system run a task that does nothing every 30 minutes.

Comment: Warning! Don't delete regedit file from > `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks ` I removed this folder. Task Screduler began to give errors.